# Stopped seeing SQL level logs on Heroku with RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I've stopped seeing my app's SQL level logs. I only see the calls for the controllers.

Haven't changed any configuration.

```
config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Logger.new(STDOUT))
```

production.rb

Has anyone experience the same with Heroku?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Heroku: see params and sql activity in logs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427096/heroku-see-params-and-sql-activity-in-logs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem.
I added

```
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT) if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
```

to produciton.rb and it started showing the SQL queries in the log again.