# How can see my database transaction queries (sql queries) on a heroku server log?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a rails application on heroku. I want to look at real time server logs like in a local server. I tried this [blog](https://blog.heroku.com/monitoring_your_heroku_postgres_database). The command heroku logs --tail lets me look at the blog but doesn't show database transactions. I want to be able to look at all database queries.

Comment: I think that you are talking not exactly about database logs. If you want to see rails ActionRecord transactions you need to switch your application ENV to development mode, or switch log level output to :debug in your production.rb. This is not recommended practice in production - so use it with care.

Comment: @OleksiiBaidan i already have `config.log_level = :debug` on my production.rb

Comment: well, this was just a direction where you need to search. In any case - think that the answer is already in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427096/heroku-see-params-and-sql-activity-in-logs

Comment: @OleksiiBaidan thank you so much for the redirect!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the `production.rb` file add `config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)` with the `config.log_level = :debug`